# Unsupervised Encoding in Keras with Custom Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to model time-varying covariance using RNNs in Keras, where I decompose the covariance of a signal Y into a time-varying weighted sum: C_Y^t = SUM_i^npriors (alpha_i^t * beta_i), where beta_i are some basis set which is fixed and alpha_i^t are the terms I am trying to infer.

As a cost function, I (currently) use the negative log-likelihood, where here the likelihood is a zero-mean MVN with the inferred covariance C_Y^t (as shown above): likelihood = MVN (Y; 0, C_Y^t). Once implemented correctly I will use the reparam trick with KL divergence.

I don't explicitly want to reconstruct my data in the classic autoencoder setup - I just want to infer the alpha terms which best fit the time varying covariance dynamics. Hence when calling my model, outputs should just be `alpha_mu` and `alpha_sigma`:

```
alpha_model_net = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs_layer],
                                  outputs= [alpha_mu,alpha_sigma], 
                                  name='Alpha_MODEL')
```

*But* I do not know what these alpha terms are *a priori*, so when calling `alpha_model_net.fit(Y_observed,[alpha_mu_predict,alpha_sigma_predict])` it is hard to know what these `[alpha_mu_predict,alpha_sigma_predict]` terms should be in the unsupervised setting.

**My question therefore comes in 2 parts:**

1. What should I feed in as `alpha_predict`, if I do not know them?
2. Am I actually using my samples from the alpha distributions, i.e.`alpha_ast` in my custom cost function in the attempted implementation shown here?

I have had a go at implementing this myself. Key parts of my code can be seen below, and [a complete example with data simulation can be found on a Google Colab doc here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1M1YQyrrE6Ir6nRsqni1OyWaX2Zf2bH9c).

**Model**

```
mini_batch_length = 10 # feature length
nchans = 5 # number of features/channels of observed data, Y
nunits = 10 # number of GRU units
npriors = 2 # i.e. how many basis functions we have

inputs_layer = layers.Input(shape=(mini_batch_length,nchans), name='Y_input')
output,state = tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(nunits, # number of units 
                                          return_state=True,
                                          return_sequences=True,
                                          name='uni_INF_GRU')(inputs_layer)

alpha_mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(npriors,activation='linear',name='alpha_mu')(output)                                  
alpha_sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(npriors,activation='linear',name='alpha_sigma')(output)                                  

# use reparameterization trick to push the sampling out as input
alpha_ast = layers.Lambda(sampling, 
                          name='alpha_ast')([alpha_mu, alpha_sigma])

# instantiate alpha MODEL network:
alpha_model_net = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs_layer],
                                  outputs= [alpha_ast], 
                                  name='Alpha_MODEL')

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(alpha_model_net, to_file='vae_mlp_encoder.png', show_shapes=True)
```

**Cost function**

```
def vae_loss(Y_portioned, alpha_ast):
  """
  Our cost function is just the NLL

  The likelihood is a multivariate normal with zero mean and time-varying
  covariance:
                  P(Y|alpha^t) = MVN(Y; 0, C_Y^t)
  where
                      C_Y^t  = SUM_i^npriors (alpha_ast_i^t beta_i)

  Y is our observed data
  alpha_ast_i^t are our samples from the inferred parameters (mu,sigma)
  beta_i are the basis functions (corresponding to covariance_matrix below)
  and (perhaps obviously) are not trainable.                                    
  """
  # Alphas need to end up being of dimension (?,mini_batch_length,npriors,1,1),
  # and need to undergo softplus transformation:
  alpha_ext = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(
    tf.keras.activations.softplus(alpha_ast),
    axis=-1),axis=-1)

  # Covariance basis set
  # This needs to be of dim [npriors, sensors, sensors]:
  covariance_basis = np.tile(np.zeros((nchans,nchans)),(npriors,1,1)).astype('float32')
  covariance_basis[0,0,0] = 1
  covariance_basis[1,1,1] = 1

  # Covariance basis functions need to be of dimension [1,1, npriors, sensors, sensors]
  covariance_ext = tf.reshape(covariance_basis,(1,1,npriors,nchans,nchans))

  # Do the multiplicative sum over the npriors dimension:
  cov_arg = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(alpha_ext,covariance_ext),2)
  safety_add = 1e-6*np.eye(nchans, nchans) 
  cov_arg = cov_arg + safety_add 

  mvn=tfd.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(
  loc = np.zeros((mini_batch_length,nchans)).astype('float32'), 
  covariance_matrix=cov_arg,
  allow_nan_stats=False)

  # Evaluate the -log(MVN) at the current batch of data. We add a tiny constant
  # to avoid any NaN or inf troubles
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(-tf.math.log(mvn.prob(Y_portioned)+1e-9))

  return loss
```

**Fit Model**

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
alpha_model_net.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=vae_loss)

history=alpha_model_net.fit(Y_portioned, # Observed data.
                            Y_portioned, # ???
                    verbose=1,
                    shuffle=True,
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=400)
```

Enormous thanks in advance - please let me know if I am missing any key details.

Using TensorFlow 2.1.0 backend.

**UPDATE 1:**
I simply used the `add_loss` function to calculate the NLL with my tensors. This now *seems* to be working, and I don't need to specify the pesty y in model.fit(x,y). Will update again if this is not correct.

**Example Model**

```
inputs_layer = layers.Input(shape=(mini_batch_length,nchans), name='Y_portioned_in')
output,state = tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(nunits, # number of units 
                                          return_state=True,
                                          return_sequences=True,
                                          name='uni_INF_GRU')(inputs_layer)

dense_layer_mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(npriors,activation='linear')(output)                                  
dense_layer_sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(npriors,activation='linear')(output)                                  

alpha_ast = layers.Lambda(sampling, 
                          name='alpha_ast')([dense_layer_mu, dense_layer_sigma])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs_layer], outputs=[dense_layer_mu])

# Construct your custom loss as a tensor
loss = my_beautiful_custom_loss(alpha_ast,inputs_layer,npriors,nchans)

# Add loss to model
model.add_loss(loss)

# Compile without specifying a loss
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt)

history=model.fit(Y_portioned, # Input or "Y_true"
                    verbose=1,
                    shuffle=True,
                    epochs=400,
                    batch_size=200)
```

where

```
def my_beautiful_custom_loss(alpha_ast,Y_portioned,npriors,nchans):
  # <Do something with input tensors here>

  return loss
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the most sensible thing to do, but I used the `add_loss` function to get around this.

I will update my original question with a complete implementation.